# Error:Property 'bypassSecurityTrustUrl' does not exist on type 'typeof CommonFunctions', when using it in a function?

Tags: angular, angular-fullstack, angular-dom-sanitizer

I want to build a common class for the frequently used statements in function.

and i am getting error if i use this keyword within a function.

```
 import {Component}  from '@angular/core';
    import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    export class CommonFunctions  {
        
        constructor(private  sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
    
        }
        static sum(a: number, b: number): number {
            return a + b;
        }
     
        static formatImage(projectList:any):any  {
            
          
            for (var index in projectList) {
                let images = projectList[index].img;
                let objectURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + images;
//error in this line
                let thumbnail1 = this.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
               projectList[index].img = thumbnail1;
        
              }
              return projectList;
            
          }




}
```

Comment: probably should be this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be :

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(...)
```

Instead of

```
this.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(...)
```